# How to disable night mode in my application even if night mode is enable in android 9.0 (pie)?

Tags: android

I created my application before the android pie has been released, in every layout I put `android: background = "white"` it works fine in every device, but when my brother installed the application and enabled `night mode` my application becomes a disaster with one single move, everything turns into back and white movie.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/COLOR_PRIMARY</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/COLOR_PRIMARY</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/COLOR_PRIMARY</item>
    <item name="cardViewStyle">@style/CardView</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/helvetica</item>
</style>
```

my color primary is red.

Comment: You must adapt your app for the night mode. Android-Q will out any time soon and all the app will get affected from the system settings . You can look for Dark theme tutorials ..

Comment: Does Android 9 (Pie) have such a feature? Did you mean Android Q?

Comment: @Leo No it's android pie

Comment: That's the thing. Android Pie doesn't have a "Dark Theme". It was introduced in Android Q

Comment: Has anyone found a workaround for expo managed apps? 
(until this gets resolved https://github.com/expo/react-native-appearance/issues/60)

Answer (score 215):

You can put this, at the first line in the `onCreate` method of your launcher activity.

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
```

Comment: Another solution I think is that you can have a Light theme, and put it in both _style.xml_  in the `values`  and  `values-night`.

Comment: just don't forget that this solution causes activity full destroy and recreation....

Comment: In React Native I've put it to MainApplication.java, but nothing changed

Comment: @inferus-vv I have no idea about React Native but try this: ```Another solution I think is that you can have a Light theme, and put it in both style.xml in the values and values-night```

Comment: The solution of style folder is best option. 

<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>

Comment: <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>    

Required API level 29

Comment: adding it to your `Application` class `onCreate` is better than this

Comment: @AliRezaiyan It is not possible

Comment: it is not working for me i have aded in my main activity is it right i have no other activitty only have fragments AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);

Comment: this worked for me, except I put it in my application file not my individual activities and fragments

Comment: @AntonisRadz i've found that using this code in Application class can prevent the activity recreation (and blinks)

Comment: this is work for me. I only put this on MainActivity, and all my activities and fragments are all in light theme

Answer (score 156):

Tested using **Xiaomi Note 8 Pro MIUI 12.0.2 Android 10**

Adding `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);` to `MainActivity.onCreate();` doesn't seems to be working

The working solution was to add `<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>` inside our main `AppTheme` block in `styles.xml`

Example:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>
</style>
```

**Update for InputMethodService :**

For `InputMethodService` / Maybe if we inflate layout in any `Service`
I found when in `Dark Mode - Xiaomi MIUI 12.0.3` there's a Black color which gets inverted into White.
To prevent the inversion, so Black color will still be Black be sure to set a theme in `InputMethodService`.

At `onCreate()` before `super.onCreate()` call these methods

- `getApplication().setTheme()`
- `setTheme()`

For your information, I'm passing `Light Theme (Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar)` which have `android:forceDarkAllowed=false`.
In my case for `InputMethodService` just calling `getApplication().setTheme()` is not enough to prevent the inversion.

Comment: This is te answer that i have looking for. In my Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 when i have the nigth mode by default in system my app when i choce day mode dont work. But whit this  <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item> in my style is working fine.

Comment: There's no styles.xml.   
   Edit: adding it in both themes.xml worked. Edit2: setDefaultNightMode is still needed for it to work.

Comment: There is a bug with edittexts, edittext hints not visibile in this case.

Comment: Your solution is available only if my minimum API level is 29. How do you suggest to do it for an app that supports lower API level?

Comment: @Yossi Hi, It ignores the minimum API if we add tools:targetApi="q" on android:forceDarkAllowed like this <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>
Or you can create styles.xml for API 29 and add the android:forceDarkAllowed in there

Answer (score 119):

In themes.xml change:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
```

to

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. However, to really disable night mode I also deleted 'themes.xml (night)'.

Comment: Change it in themes.xml for night version

Comment: don't forget to remove theme.xml file from values-night folder

Answer (score 108):

## React Native, Ionic (cordova, capacitor)

Actually, this answer is especially for **React Native** developers/apps:

Just like all of us know, the dark mode is fully available on [Android 10](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme)

> Dark theme is available in Android 10 (API level 29) and higher

And most likely this feature ruined your app design implementation, like SVG, font, and background colors. if you decided to fully disable `force dark mode` you should follow this approach:

1. *Append* the following code inside your `<style>` tag in the `styles.xml` file:

   ```xml
   <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
   ```

   **Note**: *file path*: `android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml`
2. After step *1* you shoule have something like below:

   ```xml
   <resources>
     <!-- Base application theme. -->
     <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
         ...
         <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
     </style>
   </resources>
   ```
3. **Maybe** the above steps don't help you but don't worry, just like is said in the top of this post, this feature is released on *API level 29*, this means you should change the `compileSdkVersion` to **29** or higher.
4. To Change the `compileSdkVersion` you should edit the the `compileSdkVersion` in the *app gradle* properites existed in the `android/app/build.gradle` file:

   ```
   android {
       compileSdkVersion 29
   ```
5. **Maybe** you face `compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion`, don't worry you should change this in the *android gradle* properites existed in the `android/build.gradle` file:

   ```
   buildscript {
       ext {
           buildToolsVersion = "SomeVersion"
           minSdkVersion = SomeVersion
           compileSdkVersion = 29 // <======= this should be 29 or higher
           targetSdkVersion = SomeVersion
   ```

**Hint**: For being sure that you have a new build, completely delete your last build by using the `rm -rf android/app/build` command and uninstall the app on your Emulator/Device and then run `yarn android` again.

Comment: This answer belongs to me, if have question, just mention me. thanks.

Comment: @AmerllicA I tried both your solution and the method in onCreate and nothing works. I made a new build and tried it on my Xiaomi Mi 10T Lite

Comment: @AldimirAleknsandrov, weird, because in any cases it should work, actually, with this solution you completely turned of the dark theme, please replace 30 instead of 29, maybe it works, please inform me with effects.

Comment: @AmerllicA I actually have the default at 29, and the min at 21

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work for Xiaomi devices because doesn't work either on my Xiaomi Mi 9. It could be possible because Xiaomi uses a custom theme OS (MIUI)

Comment: Worked for my Redmi Note 8, many thanks! My friend scared me when he showed up the black screen to me in his downloaded prod version. I've run `npx react-native-clean-project` before trying it out, as OP suggested to clean it up.

Comment: Is there a solution for expo?

Comment: This solution still works on SDK 30 and React 0.66.1, thanks!

Comment: not work for API 31

Answer (score 38):

If you want to avoid Activity recreations you could set the flag on the Application class as mentioned [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/appcompat-v23-2-daynight-d10f90c83e94)

> I recommend setting it in your application class (if you have one) like so:

```kotlin
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26):

What suggested by Ali Rezaiyan is the correct way to proceed if you want disable the night mode all over your app.

Sometimes you just need to disable the night mode on some activities or fragment only (maybe because of legacy stuff).

So you can choose what to do:

- Disable all over the app:

  - `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)`
- Disable for a single Activity:

  - `getDelegate().setLocalNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);`
  - After calling this you probably need to call `recreate()` for this to take effect

Comment: I had a problem that was using `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode()` in activity and this caused a call to the `onNewIntent` method when the activity start.
but `getDelegate().setLocalNightMode()` save me a day. thank you.

Answer (score 23):

This worked for me (april 2021)

1. add this line under your theme:

`<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q"> false </item>`

2. delete themes.xml (night) file (under values folder)

Comment: added this line in the `styles.xml` along with the `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`
in resources tag. It hasn't worked for me. Am I supposed to add it somewhere else?

Comment: You should add it in your 'themes.xml' file.
Can find it under : res > values > themes.xml

Comment: I'm working with react native and apparently it doesn't have a themes.xml 
Instead it has the styles.xml whit the following tags: `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">` so i figured that this must be the theme

Comment: But still the activity is restarted on theme change. How to prevent that?

Answer (score 22):

`<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">`

**change both themes DayNight to Light**

`<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">`

Comment: Non-destructive, quick and dirty fix. Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me, I changed
from `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">`
to `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`.

File path: `android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml`

All code:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 10):

create a base application class which inherits Application class and inside the override oncreate method put this line:-

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
```

also don't forget to add this under name tag in android manifest.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. There are many answers here that are misleading. the activity restart (as expected for a theme change) will only occur if this is added in an Activity. There are no restarts or other issues if this is added in the onCreate of your Application class as this answer suggests. See here: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatDelegate#setDefaultNightMode(int)

Answer (score 9):

**Do not Use below code.**

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
```

This will call your activity twice.

**Just simply Use this**

In your Theme file

First make Style parent as Light

```
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar
```

Then add this Line Under your style

```
<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>
```

So your code is look like this.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_color_app</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/status_bar_color</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>

        <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>

        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
```

**Note** : If you have android studio updated version make sure you need to make style same for Night Theme. **`Same Color as Light theme`**

Comment: According to Android documentation "If this method is called after any host components with attached AppCompatDelegates have been 'created', a uiMode configuration change will occur in each." I added this in the App class and nothing got called twice and it applied to the whole app.

Answer (score 8):

Change the DayNight to Light in AppTheme in the styles.xml file.

Answer (score 7):

in layout of your activity that you want to disable force dark, place following attribute in parent layout:

```
android:forceDarkAllowed="false"
```

your layout should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:forceDarkAllowed="false">

<!-- ..... -->

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This doesn't work on all views in the xml. I have to manually add this line to textviews. The good solution is adding  
        <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
in styles folder

Comment: how to prevent  from inverting the notification image with darkmode .

Answer (score 7):

Just Modify the few changes below in your project (themes.xml):

If your Android studio has the latest version, then apply this on both "themes.xml" and "themes.xml(night)".

Change:

```
<style name="Theme.demo" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">`
```

To:

```
<style name="Theme.demo" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
```

And then just add the below line:

```
<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>
```

Comment: Great man, you make my day :) :) :)

Answer (score 6):

use this as parent for disable dark mode
parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

Answer (score 5):

Just add 
`AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);`  
after
 `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

on every Activity

Next add 
 `<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>` 
  in your Theme.

Comment: i have tried this, however it did not have any effect.

Answer (score 4):

Go and add:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

in your **theme**, even if dark mode is enabled in you're device. Light theme is applied in your application.

Answer (score 3):

I have gone through a lot of solutions but none was robust until I removed the "values-night" folder from the "res" folder.

```
And change use parent theme: <style name="Theme.CryptoKite" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Comment: This in addition to QB Tech's solution is perfect for me.

Answer (score 3):

This line of code works for me.

```
<!--To disable dark mode-->
<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>
```

Answer (score 2):

using the following line can help you to not overload dark mode in your app.

```
android:forceDarkAllowed="false"
```

Example of usage,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:forceDarkAllowed="false"
tools:context=".SplashActivity">
```

Comment: This must be added to styles.xml

Answer (score 2):

Another option for Cordova only developers:

From https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/dark-theme

"WebView can't differentiate based solely on the presence of the media query, so it needs a color-scheme meta tag with dark value as indication that a web page has its own dark theme. To prevent double-darkening (that is, applying color inversion on top of media query customization) WebView evaluates @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) to false in this mode."

So I added `<meta name="color-scheme" content="dark">` to my html and presto - it now detects my prefers-color-scheme: dark query and doesnt apply auto darkening.

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me in a Cordova app

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Fauzi Danartha's answer to IMS part.
One can extend theme with

```
<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q"> false </item>
```

not from material design's themes but from `android:Theme.DeviceDefault.InputMethod` (since targetSdkVersion 14).

Also calling `getApplication().setTheme()` is not necessary, just `setTheme()` is enough.

Checked on MIUI 12.0.4.

Answer (score 2):

for me I had to add `<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>` in the `Theme.App.SplashScreen` style also, Im using expo bare.

```xml
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
  <!-- Base application theme. -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
  </style>
  <style name="Theme.App.SplashScreen" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Below line is handled by '@expo/configure-splash-screen' command and it's discouraged to modify it manually -->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashscreen</item>
    <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
    <!-- Customize your splash screen theme here -->
  </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 2):

Never add this code:

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
```

If you put it in your oncreate Method of MainActivity, the onCreate method will called twice!!! It take me an hour to find out that adding this line caused the problem!

just add this line in your style.xml:

```
<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>
```

it looks like this in my code:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this worked for my apps too(which build on react 17 and capacitor v5). i had similar problem when Xiaomi phone get darkmode active.

Answer (score 2):

Change both Light and Dark themes to the same colours.
That will not affect output even if the device is in dark mode.

Inside both `value/theme.xml` and `night/theme.xml`

Change the following line

```
<style name="Theme.Labmuffles" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

to

```
<style name="Theme.Labmuffles" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
```

The app will be in dark mode but even in the dark mode it will display colours of the light mode and it will stay always light.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the kotline. In my case, I've added the following lines in the below of oncreate method

in an activity class and

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)

 }
```

and in the value->styles->Themes/style class, I add the following code

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:ignore="NewApi">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: If you want to force the use Light theme in the whole app, you can  add that line of code within the onCreate of your Application class.

Answer (score 1):

After adding `<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>` to the `styles.xml` file, dont forget to change parent theme from

```
Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar
```

to

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar
```

uninstall app from the emulator, run `cd android && ./gradlew clean` and it should be working fine.

Answer (score 1):

simply deleting the darkmode theme from themes folder worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Change this

```
<style name="YourThemeName" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DarkActionBar">
```

To

```
<style name="YourThemeName" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

In both theme and theme night

and make sure all colors are same in the theme and theme night

Comment: It doesnt affect.. Becuase android system automatically changes colors of app.. Background colors or text colors arent declared in styles for many times

Answer (score 0):

I have this force night mode problem in redmi note 7 pro. But, when I use

AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);

this method in my application level class and the whole app theme was changed as light theme but actually I wanted the theme as night too.

And I found solution for particular view as:

android:forceDarkAllowed="false"

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white_black"
    android:elevation="@dimen/dim4"
    android:forceDarkAllowed="false"
    android:forceHasOverlappingRendering="false"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/highlighted_bottom_nav_item"
    app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/BottomNavigationView.Active"
    app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/BottomNavigationView"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/highlighted_bottom_nav_item"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

And just fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

in your themes folder
themes.xml (night)
change this :

```
<style name="Theme.PooyaProteinOperator"parent=" Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
```

to this

```
<style name="Theme.PooyaProteinOperator" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

and add this in block style if your using api 29 or above

```
<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:target="Q">false</item>
```

Answer (score -2):

*This is an easy way:*

Copy the content of the first file located at **res>values>themes** and paste it into the second file in the same directory.

[image: values]