# How to disable automatic change of day night theme based on android system settings?

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-theme, android-dark-theme, android-darkmode

So far I have learnt from google, you have to use **Theme.Appcompat.Daynight** or Material Daynight theme to make your app support dark mode. And you need to use different **styles.xml** in **values** and **values-night** directories.
I am not willing to make my app support dark theme. But when I change android system theme (from notification panel) to dark, my app becomes dark.
I am using **Theme.Appcompat.Light** as base theme, did nothing for my app to support dark mode, still my app becomes dark. I am using cardview for the very first time, don't know if it may be the cause since I am very new in android programming.
Your little help will be much welcome. Please, check screenshots here:

[System dark mode off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92zQU.jpg)

[System dark mode on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaU7u.jpg)

Comment: Hi. Have you already checked out this question? This might be a duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57175226/how-to-disable-night-mode-in-my-application-even-if-night-mode-is-enable-in-andr/57175501

Comment: Yeah, I see, our problems are almost same, but I am not using Theme.AppCompat.DayNight as application base theme. And the solution provided there, AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO) - doesn't work for me. 

Answer (score 4):

You can use this in all application

```
class AppController: Application() {
   override fun onCreate() {
      super.onCreate()
      AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
   }
}
```

Comment: This worked and is apparently the best way to do this. See https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/appcompat-v23-2-daynight-d10f90c83e94

Answer (score 1):

in android 10 ,android forse dark to app to pervent that ,
add below to your defult theme in style :

```
 <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line inside onCreate method of the MainActivity before calling setContentView:

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) For example, you can add a working example based on the question details.