# How to disable dark theme in xamarin forms for real?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin-forms-shell

**First question**

My app is only for internal use so I never ever need dark theme support. I use the newest xamarin forms.
How to disable dark theme globally in app?
It's pretty easy in ios subproject.

**Second question**

How to change color of border of text entry in light and dark mode? I can change it in subprojects with custom reneders but I need comprehensive solution for shared project.

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking.. if you are not setting it up then the style used for your app is independent from dark/light theme. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/app-themes-xamarin-forms/

Comment: @NightCity10932 You want to change app theme? If yes, please take a look [Theme a Xamarin.Forms Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/theming/theming)

Comment: Put this in App.xaml.cs constructor : Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.UserAppTheme = OSAppTheme.Light;  It will keep your app in Light theme.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64755827

Comment: It isn’t duplicate because there is no real answer in your link. Create project with shell or tabbed page in the newest visual studio from template and deploy it to your smartphone. I use Huawei P30 and my app is not theme independent. I don’t want to use appthemebinding. I prefer disable it for real.

Comment: @NightCity10932 If you want to disable dark theme, you consider to change theme using resourcedictionary?

Comment: For Android I used this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68622874/6846888

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a new CustomerRenderer, like this one:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pWvYNZOQo-A&ab_channel=AyberkZeray

then modify the info.plist with this lines (open the file with a text editor):

```
<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
<string>Light</string>
```

Comment: thats no longer working. Apple will reject your app

Comment: Damm Apple.. what's the solution now? to edit the answer

Comment: to implement dark mode, apple trying to force you to have.

Answer (score 0):

For customizing for dark mode is not super difficult

In the view use AppThemeBinding like the below, can be applied against different attributes to give different color based off Light or Dark Mode.

```
BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=BlanchedAlmond, Dark=Black}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your MainActivity.cs file,
add :

```
using AndroidX.AppCompat.App;
```

Then, after the `base.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` :

```
AppCompatDelegate.DefaultNightMode = AppCompatDelegate.ModeNightNo;
```