# Text color is overridden to white when tested on a device with Android 10 in dark mode

Tags: react-native

In the following React Native (0.63.3) app, text color is black on the emulator as expected, but overridden to white when tested on a device with Android 10 in dark mode.

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#ccc"}}>
      <Text style={{color: "#000"}}>Test</Text>
    </View>
  );
  
};

export default App;
```

What should be done?

(It also overrides #333, #345 or similar dark shades to lighter colors. Border colors and more are overridden too but let's keep the question simple.)

Comment: What device are you testing on? It could be device specific dark mode that's being applied.

Comment: You could check if this answer works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64339016/3156644

Comment: Adding <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item> to styles.xml definitely works. But this default behaviour which even overrides the inline styles is confusing and should be changed in React Native default installation in my opinion.

Answer (score 29):

Android Apps by default uses `DayNight` configuration that try to support both light and dark themes. [android doc about dark themes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme) . But it won't work well with theme overriding.

The solution is changing the app to only light mode.

Edit: `android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml`

```
replace this line:
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
with this:
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Answer (score 4):

Define default text color for android like so

> Edit: android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
     <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</resources>
```