# React native paper Android 11 devices Textinput not showing

Tags: android, react-native, textinput, react-native-paper

I am using reat natiev paper for outline textinput in my react native app so below is my code

```
const TextInput = ({...props }) => (
 <View style={styles.container}>
  <Input
  style={styles.input}
  selectionColor={colors.black}
  underlineColor="transparent"
  mode="outlined"
  autoCapitalize="none"
  activeOutlineColor={colors.black60}
  {...props}
   />
  </View> 
 );

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: '100%',
    // marginBottom: 5,
  },
 input: {
   backgroundColor: colors.white,
   fontSize: commonTheme.TEXT_SIZE_DEFAULT,
   fontFamily: globals.RobotoRegular,
 },

});
```

export default TextInput;

here my main tsx file i am calling above textinput component

```
<TextInput
  label="Email"
  value={values.email}
  keyboardType="email-address"
  placeholder="Enter Address"
  onChangeText={handleChange('email')}
  onBlur={handleBlur('email')}
  textContentType="emailAddress"
 />
```

when i run above code on Android 11 OS devices textinput not showing when i focus at that time using

[image]

Comment: Does your device has enabled Dark Mode?

Comment: Yes @VickyAhuja Dar mode enabled in my device

Comment: Try after disabling the dark mode

Comment: Yes it is working after light mode convert , any solution for dark mode because generally user switch in dark mode in mobile @VickyAhuja

Comment: I am attaching the procedure in answer

Comment: Check out this alternative https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66368126/text-color-is-overridden-to-white-when-tested-on-a-device-with-android-10-in-dar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the issue you are having might be because of the dark mode enabled on your device.

Often the design issues we face are because of the dark mode.

There are mostly two ways to handle the design in the case of dark mode.

1. Either you have to give support for both dark and light modes with your code
2. Or you do have to make force light mode for your app

To force the app to work in light mode even if the device has enabled the dark mode:

Add the following line of code inside your  tag of the **base application theme** in the styles.xml file:

```
<resources>
  <!-- Base application theme. -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
      ...
      <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```