# How to fix image view icon color changes in dark mode and lite mode of the device

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-icons, android-darkmode

I'm trying to include icons in imageview but when the dark mode is on the color is dark and when on lite mode its shows in white, I want color to be white in both modes

****Vector**** // icon

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:tint="@color/white"
    android:viewportHeight="24" android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="@color/white" android:pathData="M20,11H7.83l5.59,-5.59L12,4l-8,8 8,8 1.41,-1.41L7.83,13H20v-2z"/>
</vector>
```

****ImageView**** // icon included as background

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backArrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_back_24"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        android:elevation="10dp" />
```

**themes.xml** // litemod/normal

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.MyAppNotFinal" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">#FFFFFFFF</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/lite_grey</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/AppBottomSheetDialogTheme</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**themes.xml** // dark mod/night

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.MyAppNotFinal" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">#FFFFFFFF</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/AppBottomSheetDialogTheme</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="purple_200">#FFBB86FC</color>
    <color name="purple_500">#FF6200EE</color>
    <color name="purple_700">#FF3700B3</color>
    <color name="teal_200">#FF03DAC5</color>
    <color name="teal_700">#FF018786</color>
    <color name="black">#000000</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
    <color name="grey">#181818</color>
    <color name="lite_grey">#e2e2e2</color>
    <color name="dark_red">#bd081c</color>
    <color name="green">#0B5B37</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i got an answer to my question, acttualy my app already has dark elements and when i add a white background to an imageview or some more elements but it changes to dark grey in the dark mod of the device which i dont want ,so i got an solution to this issue

**Step 1**

Delete the night/dark theme.xml in the values

**Step 2**

In the normal/light theme.xml in the values change the

```
<style name="Theme.MyAppNotFinal" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

to

```
<style name="Theme.MyAppNotFinal" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
```

**Step 3**

In the same theme.xml // light/normal theme

add this line

```
 <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>
```

inside the style

like this

```
<style name="Theme.MyAppNotFinal" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>
</style>
```

this method worked for me if anyone still have some issues please check the bellow question it has many answers hope it will work for you

[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57175226/how-to-disable-night-mode-in-my-application-even-if-night-mode-is-enable-in-andr)