# How to disable Darktheme when using Jetpack compose in Android app?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have an Android app and it is currently in MVP state some of the users use their phone in Dark mode. There is no time to optimize for Dark theme.

I already tried passing same light theme colors to the Material theme does not work.

Also tried this  but didn't work,

```
AppTheme(false) {
  content()
}
```

because theme composable says,

```
fun AppTheme(darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(), content: @Composable() () -> Unit) {
}
```

Comment: You only disabled it in the Compose part, but you also need to do it in the Android part (which is at a lower level than Compose), for example, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57175226/).

Answer (score 3):

Go to MainActivity  add darkTheme = false just like it.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        installSplashScreen()
        setContent {
           DemoAppTheme(darkTheme = false) {
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Philip Dukhov for reference, basically need to use a descendant of

```
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light
```

in themes.xml

Answer (score 0):

if you use [material theme builder](https://m3.material.io/theme-builder#/custom) that is also recommended by google team at the end of the generated file Theme.kt, you will have such a code:

```
@Composable
fun AppNameTheme(
    useDarkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colors = if (!useDarkTheme) {
        LightColors
    } else {
        DarkColors
    }
    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = colors,
        content = content, typography = Typography
    )
}
```

so if you just set `val colors = LightColors` the app will remain in light mode eveen if user change its device mode to dark

Answer (score -1):

Set `useDarkTheme` to `false` instead of `isSystemInDarkTheme()` in the `Theme.kt` file. This ensures that the application doesn't check whether or not the phone has dark theme enabled.

```
@Composable
fun AppNameTheme(
    useDarkTheme: Boolean = false,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colors = if (!useDarkTheme) {
        LightColors
    } else {
        DarkColors
    }
    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = colors,
        content = content, typography = Typography
    )
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but probably unnecessary. It only changes the default value, ie. when a useDarkTheme value is not provided when calling the function. The right thing to do is to set the colorScheme directly.