# React Native FontFamily Bold and color globally not working

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, mobile

I have an issue which the `font-family` not working on my app, especially when applying bold text, I've already placed all of my font in my `android/app/src/main/assets/fonts` and doing `react-native link` command

**./constants/theme.js**

```
import { Dimensions } from "react-native";
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");
export const FONTS = {
        h1: { fontFamily: "Roboto-Black", fontSize: SIZES.h1, lineHeight: 36 },
        h2: { fontFamily: "Roboto-Bold", fontSize: SIZES.h2, lineHeight: 30 },
        h3: { fontFamily: "Roboto-Bold", fontSize: SIZES.h3, lineHeight: 22 },
        h4: { fontFamily: "Roboto-Bold", fontSize: SIZES.h4, lineHeight: 22 },
        body1: { fontFamily: "Roboto-Regular", fontSize: SIZES.body1, lineHeight: 36 },
        body2: { fontFamily: "Roboto-Regular", fontSize: SIZES.body2, lineHeight: 30 },
        body3: { fontFamily: "Roboto-Regular", fontSize: SIZES.body3, lineHeight: 22 },
        body4: { fontFamily: "Roboto-Regular", fontSize: SIZES.body4, lineHeight: 22 },
        body5: { fontFamily: "Roboto-Regular", fontSize: SIZES.body5, lineHeight: 22 },
    };

export const COLORS = {
    primary: "#7F5DF0",     // Light purple
    secondary: "#5D2DFD",   // Dark purple
    white: "#fff",
    black: "#000000",
    green: "#37E39F",
    red: "#F9A8BA",
    gray: "#6A6A6A",
    lightGray: "#dbdbdb",
    lightGray1: "#f5f6fa"
};  
export const SIZES = {
    // global sizes
    base: 8,
    font: 14,
    radius: 12,
    padding: 24,
    // font sizes
    h1: 30,
    h2: 22,
    h3: 16,
    h4: 14,
    body1: 30,
    body2: 22,
    body3: 16,
    body4: 14,
    body5: 12,
    // app dimensions
    width,
    height
};

const appTheme = { COLORS, SIZES, FONTS };
export default appTheme;
```

**And when I return it** when I use `...FONTS.h3` the text was not bold even though I declared bold text

```
 import {COLORS, FONTS} from '../constants';
 <View>
    <Text style={{...FONTS.h3, ...COLORS.green}}>Text with bold and green color</Text>
 </View>
```

**./contants/index.js**

```
import icons from "./icons";
import images from "./images";
import theme, { COLORS, SIZES, FONTS } from "./theme";

export { icons, images, theme, COLORS, SIZES, FONTS };
```

Comment: I've the same issue, did you find the solution ?

Comment: @Kishan Somaiya Not yet

Comment: Do you by any chance have dark mode enabled in your device/emulator ? Because in my case black text was rendering in white because I had dark mode enabled in my device.

Comment: @KishanSomaiya Did you solve this by changing dark mode to light mode? Yes I observed when my phone is in the dark mode the text would become white

Comment: This Answer Solved my Issue you can try it too : https://stackoverflow.com/a/64339016/14312868 Do let me know if this works it or not for you.